# doc-view failing for some PDFs, but ghostscript can view them?

Tags: pdf, docview

When I use `docview` to view PDFs on my work computer (a redhat linux system) it always works, *except* in PDFs coming from Springer-Verlag articles and chapters.  In that case it gives this error:

```
Invalid format operation %A
```

However, I *can* view such files using `gs` directly.

I have no such problem on my home iMac.  The version of `gs` that I have at work is 9.07, and the version of emacs is 24.3.1.  I checked customize and there are no nonstandard settings there for `doc-view`.

**Why is `docview` failing to load this PDF, even though `gs` can do it?  How do I fix the problem?**

Comment: Not sure about your question, but the [pdf-tools](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools) package provides a much nicer alternative to doc-view for pdfs. It uses poppler rather than gs as a display engine, so might not suffer from the same issue. I haven't noticed any problems and I'm sure some of my pdfs are from Springer.

Comment: I think that I found the problem -- it's in the file name.  All of the files from Springer have a '%' in them.  When I rename them to a name without the '%' things work fine.  There must be some sort of bug in doc-view elisp that was fixed in the version that I have on the iMac.

Comment: Do try Tyler's suggestion regardless of your workaround. Viewing PDFs in Emacs with pdf-tools is *so much nicer* than it is with doc-view.

Comment: pdf-tools might be nice, but since I'm not a sysadmin, I can't install it.

Comment: I see that this was reported as a bug in 24.3: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2014-11/msg00314.html

Comment: How do I get the elisp source that corrects this bug and still works in 24.3.1 (i.e. where are the old versions of elisp kept?)